# Getting null value from 2nd level nested json array when using apex_json :

Tags: oracle-apex

### I  have tried several options, not sure what I am missing? thanks much. the filter_value in output always seems to be null. I am expecting to see something like this:
FILTER array count : 2

### lov_for : Ids
v_count_2 : 3

### filter_value : 1
filter_value : 2
filter_value : 3

### lov_for : Amounts
v_count_2 : 4

filter_value : 20
filter_value : 30
filter_value : 50
filter_value : 60

```
DECLARE

v_a     VARCHAR2(5000) := 
        '{
        "lovFilters": [
            {
            "lovFor": "Ids",
            "values": [1,2,3]
            }, 
            {
            "lovFor": "Amounts",
            "values": [20,30,50,60]
            }
        ]
        }';

v_array_count   NUMBER := 0;
lov_for         VARCHAR2(30);
filter_value    VARCHAR2(256);
v_count_2       NUMBER:= 0;

BEGIN
    APEX_JSON.parse(v_a);

v_array_count := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'lovFilters');

dbms_output.put_line ('FILTER array count : '||v_array_count);

FOR lr_i IN 1 .. v_array_count
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line ('-------------------------');
    lov_for := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2 (p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].lovFor', p0 => lr_i);

    dbms_output.put_line ('lov_for : '||lov_for); 
    
    v_count_2 := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].values', p0 => lr_i);
    
    dbms_output.put_line ('v_count_2 : '||v_count_2);
    
    dbms_output.put_line ('--------------------------');
    
    FOR lr_n IN 1 .. v_count_2
    LOOP
        filter_value := 
            APEX_JSON.get_varchar2(p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].values[%d]', p0 => lr_i, p1 => lr_n, p_values => l_json_values);
        
        dbms_output.put_line ('filter_value : '||filter_value);        
    END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was. Your code complained about l_json_values not being defined - maybe you copied some code from elsewhere ?
The following works:

```
DECLARE
  l_json_text       VARCHAR2(5000);
  l_json_values     apex_json.t_values;
  l_array_count     NUMBER := 0;
  l_lov_for         VARCHAR2(30);
  l_filter_value    VARCHAR2(256);
  l_count_2         NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  l_json_text  := 
          '{
          "lovFilters": [
              {
              "lovFor": "Ids",
              "values": [1,2,3]
              }, 
              {
              "lovFor": "Amounts",
              "values": [20,30,50,60]
              }
          ]
          }';
  apex_json.parse(
    p_values => l_json_values,
    p_source => l_json_text
  );

  l_array_count := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'lovFilters',p_values => l_json_values);
  dbms_output.put_line ('FILTER array count : '||l_array_count);

  FOR lr_i IN 1 .. l_array_count
  LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line ('-------------------------');
      l_lov_for := APEX_JSON.get_varchar2 (p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].lovFor', p0 => lr_i, p_values => l_json_values);
      dbms_output.put_line ('l_lov_for : '||l_lov_for); 
      
      l_count_2 := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].values', p0 => lr_i, p_values => l_json_values);      
      dbms_output.put_line ('l_count_2 : '||l_count_2);      
      dbms_output.put_line ('--------------------------');
      
      FOR lr_n IN 1 .. l_count_2
      LOOP
          l_filter_value := 
              APEX_JSON.get_varchar2(p_path => 'lovFilters[%d].values[%d]', p0 => lr_i, p1 => lr_n, p_values => l_json_values);          
          dbms_output.put_line ('l_filter_value : '||l_filter_value);        
      END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the missing component. appreciate it.